# How can I apply `cut` to several files and then `paste` the results?

Tags: zsh, cut, paste

I often do operations like

```
paste <(cut -d, -f1 file1.csv) <(cut -d, -f1 file2.csv)
```

which is very tedious with more than a few files.

Can I automate this process, e.g. with globbing? I can save the `cut` results with

```
typeset -A cut_results
for f in file*.csv; do
    cut_results[$f]="$(cut -d, -f1 $f)"
done
```

but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: https://github.com/thrig/sial.org-scripts/blob/master/misc/stitch is what I use for something like this task.

Comment: Sometimes if the no. of fields/columns is known you could also [paste all files and then cut the fields you need](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235681)...

Comment: cat | cut | paste?

Comment: @MaxRied that doesn't do what want.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Doesn't `cat file*.csv | cut -d, -f1 | paste` do what you try to archive?

Comment: @MaxRied nope, try it and see the difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can automate this with globbing, specifically the `e` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), plus `eval`, but it isn't pretty and the quoting is tricky:

```
eval paste *.csv(e\''REPLY="<(cut -d, -f1 $REPLY)"'\')
```

- The part between `\'…\'` is some code to execute for every match of the glob. It is executed with the variable `REPLY` set to the match, and can modify it.
- I put the code in single quotes so that it isn't expanded when the glob is parsed.
- The code `REPLY="<(cut -d, -f1 $REPLY)"` generates the string `<(cut -d, -f1 file1.csv)` if the match is `file1.csv`. The double quotes are necessary so that the part after the equal sign isn't expanded when the `e` code is executed apart from substituting the value of `REPLY`.
- Since each globbed file is replaced by a string,

It would be nicer to hide the complexity in a function. Minimally tested.

```
function map {
  emulate -LR zsh
  local cmd pre
  cmd=()
  while [[ $# -ne 0 && $1 != "--" ]]; do
    cmd+=($1)
    shift
  done
  if ((!$#)); then
    echo >&2 "Usage: $0: COMMAND [ARGS...] -- PREPROCESSOR [ARGS...] -- FILES..."
    return 125
  fi
  shift
  while [[ $# -ne 0 && $1 != "--" ]]; do
    pre+="${(q)1} "
    shift
  done
  if ((!$#)); then
    echo >&2 "Usage: $0: COMMAND [ARGS...] -- PREPROCESSOR [ARGS...] -- FILES..."
    return 125
  fi
  shift
  eval "${(@q)cmd}" "<($pre${(@q)^@})"
}
```

Sample usage (the syntax is reminiscent of `zargs`):

```
map paste -- cut -d, -f1 -- *.csv
```

Comment: Great tip about the `e` qualifier, and great idea wrapping it in a generic "mapping" function.

Comment: Of course, this chokes when you have to pass `--` as an argument to one of the utilities but I don't think I'm going to run into that edge case

Comment: One solution would be to copy `find`'s syntax, using a shell-escaped semicolon to end the command and a placeholder string for the argument

Answer (score 4):

I think your first line is about as good as it gets for a simple one-liner.

If there are a bunch of files with all different names, you could reduce the repetitive typing a bit with a simple history expansion "cheat":

First run `<(cut -d, -f1`

Note the trailing space.  Also note that this command will give you a secondary prompt; just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.  The only point is to add it to the history.

Next run `paste !!file1.csv) !!file2.csv)`

The `!!` will expand to the full content of the previous command run, including the trailing space.  Note that if you forget the trailing close parentheses you will get a secondary prompt; you can just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and try again if this happens.

This is a bit hacky but good enough for a one-time use.  If you're doing it a lot, you might write a bash function.

Answer (score 3):

Try **awk**

```
awk '{L[FNR]=L[FNR] $1 "\t"}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print L[i]}' *.csv
```

or **paste** with **sed**

```
paste *.csv | sed 's/ [^\t]*//g'
```

Comment: I always forget I can use AWK for multiple files. This is definitely the best answer for my specific use case, but I'm accepting the "map" answer because it's closer to what I had in mind with this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm studying `bash` scripting at the moment, and this seemed an excellent simple task to practice with, so I wrote the following.  (My other answer gives the simple history expansion hack, but this is a full script and I deemed it worthy of making an additional answer.)  I *believe* this is POSIX compatible and should work with `#!/bin/sh`, but not 100% sure.  **EDIT:** Actually, the `=~` is not POSIX compatible.  You could take that check out and let `cut` return the error, though.

```
#!/bin/bash

fieldtocut=1
delimiter=','

usage () {
    cat << EOF
usage: $0 [-f FIELD] [-d DELIMITER] file1..
Cuts field FIELD from each file and pastes it.
Default field is 1, default delimiter is ','
EOF
    exit $1
}

while getopts ':f:d:' opt ; do
    case $opt in
        f)
            if [[ $OPTARG =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
                fieldtocut="$OPTARG"
            else
                usage 1
            fi
            ;;
        d)
            delimiter=$OPTARG
            ;;
        *)
            usage 1
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

[ $# -eq 0 ] && usage 0

pasteargs=''

for file in "$@" ; do
    pasteargs=$(printf '%s' "$pasteargs" '<(cut -d$delimiter -f$fieldtocut ' "$file" ') ')
done

eval paste $pasteargs
```

Comment: Your script will fail if the delimiter (or the field to cut) is a shell special character, e.g. `;` or tab, or if the file names contain shell special characters.

Comment: Grrr.  Good spotting.  Lost track of my quoting.  I tried a couple of other ways, but I got confused with the quoting and ended up making it even less workable.  Any advices on it, for learning purposes?  :)

Comment: In zsh you can just use `${(q)delimiter}`. If you want code that also works in bash, it's harder; I think `quoted_single_quote=\'\\\'\'; delimiter="'${delimiter//'/"$quoted_single_quote"}'"` works in ksh93, bash and zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your arguments are in `"$@"`,  I believe something like:

```
eval "paste $(printf "<( cut -d, -f1 %q ) " "$@")"
```

should do it.

Comment: you may run into command line length problems with the kind of approach, but,

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it that's very similar to the answer by [Wildcard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236888/73256):

```
files=( file1.csv file2.csv)
eval paste "<( cut -d, -f1 ${^files[@]} )"
```

Instead of a `for` loop, this uses the `${^ ... }` expansion which is Zsh-specific.

The reason `files` must be assigned first is that globbing is always done last, so if `files` needs to be generated automatically (as in `files=( *.csv )`) then something like `${^:-( *.csv )}` would expand only after all the other expansions have occurred. We want it to expand *first*.

The `${^ ... }` expansion causes the resulting array to act like the result of brace expansion. For example, assign `x=(a b)` and then compare `echo ${x}y` to `echo ${^x}y`.

The quoting is necessary to trick Zsh into treating the surrounding text like a literal string. Otherwise, it would split the command line at the spaces, so our `${^ ... }` expansion would reduce to `""${^ ... }""`; that is, each element would be surrounded only by an empty string. That is,

```
echo "<( cut -d, -f1 ${^files[@]} )"
```

and

```
echo "<( cut -d, -f1 "\
${^files[@]}\
" )"
```

are equivalent, but are not the same as

```
echo <( cut -d, -f1 ${^files[@]} )
```

But quoting introduces a new problem: the command line is parsed and split without regard to the expansion taking place. That is, even though we have effectively entered

```
paste <( cut -d, -f1 file1.csv ) <( cut -d, -f1 file2.csv )
```

as desired, this is in fact parsed as

```
paste '<( cut -d, -f1 file1.csv )' '<( cut -d, -f1 file2.csv )'
```

Therefore we need `eval` to re-parse the correctly formed expression. To see this in action, compare

```
setopt noxtrace
eval paste "<( cut -d, -f1 ${^files[@]} )" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

to

```
setopt xtrace
eval paste "<( cut -d, -f1 ${^files[@]} )" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

I hoped that some combination of nested expansions, the `${ ... :- ... }` expansion, and the parameter expansion flags `Q`, `z`, and/or `s` would lead to re-evaluation without `eval`, but evidently that's not the case. I also wish there was a way to force globbing, but again that seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You could get `awk` to loop through the files in lockstep and report the field of interest from each file. Put this code into a file, say `cut_files.awk`

```
NR == FNR{printf "%s%s",$1, FS;
for (k=2; k<ARGC; ++k)
    {getline < ARGV[k]; printf "%s%s", $1, k==ARGC-1?"\n":FS}; next};
NR != FNR{for (k=2; k<ARGC; ++k) close(ARGV[k]); exit}
```

And then call it like so

```
awk -F',' -f cut_files.awk file1 file2 file3 file4 ....
```